# Difference in capitalization (javascript)

Tags: javascript, capitalization

I noticed in my code that I used .Length and .length (for an array).  I now in some languages, this doesn't work.  What happened here?  Are these things just not case sensitive?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JavaScript is case sensitive.  One thing that's possible is that someone added a property called Length to Array's prototype in your codebase.